# Button press-animation lags when pressed

Tags: swiftui, async-await

I have a button that invokes an async function that applies a filter to an image. When I press the button, the button press-animation (which is built in) lags, even when the function I'm calling is async. The function is quite cpu intensive, but shouldn't the animation be smooth no matter what? What can I do to stop this from happening? I was thinking of doing a delay of a few 100 us or something before the function is actually called, but that seems like a hack that shouldn't be needed. I won't include all of my code, but it goes something like this:

```
@State private var filterType: Int = 0
.
.
.
Button {
  filterType = 1
} label: {
  ZStack {
    Rectangle()
      .fill(.red)
      .frame(width: 200: height: 30)

    Text("Press me")
      .foregroundColor(.white)
  }
}
.
.
.
MyImageView()
  .onChange(of: filterType) {
    Task {
      await applyFilter()
    }
  }
.
.
.
func applyFilter() async {
  // doing some cpu-intensive stuff here
}
```

Maybe I should rethink the structure of my code, but I don't really se why the button animation lags when it's pressed. This doesn't happen if I replace the code in the applyFunction()-function with a sleep, it only happens when doing all the actual calculations in the code.

Comment: you should submit your ** calculations** code.

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-8wgw9) for `onChange`, it is mentioned that:

> The system may call the action closure on the main actor, so avoid long-running tasks in the closure. If you need to perform such tasks, detach an asynchronous background task.

It looks like `applyFilter` is running on the main actor as the wrapping `Task` inherits the current actor.

Using `Task.detached` will execute the function on another thread and avoid blocking the main one which is responsible for UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried everything suggested, but finally found out that it was the .scaledToFit() on my Image that made everything lag when using really large images. I solved it by creating a smaller preview image to show in the view.